# 'GitLab Flow' without master branch

Tags: git, continuous-integration, branch

I am trying to come up with a modified branching strategy to fit a specific use case, while avoiding the addition of a 'master' branch.  My goal here is to avoid the approach in which master branch is always deployable.  On a high level, I just want a Dev, feature, release and hotfix branches.

In my case, I would like to deploy from multiple release branches that are simultaneously 'in flight'.  What I mean, is that the team would be creating release branches from the volatile 'Dev' branch and working on January, February, etc releases in parallel.  The issue is, once a release is ready and deployed, what is the process of merging it back to Dev, if there is no master branch?

My other question is related to having multiple release branches being worked on in parallel.  I wonder how does one assure that the code in the January release, is reconciled with February release if they are both in flight.

What is the best practice in such a use case?

Comment: As you have already noticed, this approach will create more confusions. It is better to stick to Scrum process. One release branch and may be you can have a staging branch for integration testing before release. Each team can develop in their own feature branch & merge changes to staging as and when a certain feature is ready. This way, only staging branch needs to be maintained by SCM and feature branches are taken care by developers. Otherwise maintenance of all monthly branches falls on SCM plate, overwhelming them with unnecessary merge conflicts when common modules change a lot.

Comment: So, in effect, the approach you suggested has the 'staging' branch acting as master?

Comment: In my view, staging may be more "deploy-able" with features for upcoming release when compared to master. In this way, once Jan release is complete, you can merge staging to release and continue with Feb QA Cycle.